# Vaadin MSSQLGenerator with a table inside a named schema causes error

Tags: sql-server, vaadin7

I tried to use a Vaadin MSSQLGenerator to generate a SQLContainer from a SQL Server 2012 table inside a named schema foo. Something like this:

```
MSSQLGenerator msql = new MSSQLGenerator();
TableQuery tq = new TableQuery(tableName, conPool, msql);
```

but this causes a 'Primary key constraints have not been defined for the table' error.

Notice this only happens when the table is inside a named schema different that dbo. For instance: foo.tableName

Any workaround or advice on this? I can not change the foo schema by the way or move the table to dbo schema.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 7.1. Vaadin allows to pass catalog and schema to TableQuery constructor.

new TableQuery("catalog", "schema", "table", pool, msqlgenerator)